# Generate barcode on a existing PDF with TCPDF

Tags: php, pdf, barcode, tcpdf

I used to dynamically create PDF documents and barcodes with HTML using TCPDF.

To generate the barcode options the `serializeTCPDFtagParameters` method is used and later `<tcpdf method="write1DBarcode" params="PARAMS" />` is passed to the PDF's HTML.

Now, I need to generate a barcode and then insert on each page of an existing PDF template.

Is it possible to generate a barcode for an existing PDF using TCPDF library?

Comment: Have you checked out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26029065/tcpdf-import-is-not-bringing-in-an-existing-file ?

Comment: I don't think it's ready for prime-time though, so good luck! http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/tcpdf__import_8php.html

Comment: Can you use a barcode font, or do you need to create an image? (hint: a font is preferred)