# PHP generate PDF and edit

Tags: javascript, php, pdf

I would like to ask

Is it possible to edit the PDF file? For example, insert a new pages between pages , like add page between page 17 and 19.

Which library can i use?

Answer (score 0):

one way to do this is to use ghostscript to split the pdf into individual page images and then you can add additional pages and rearrange pages as needed with tcpdf or similar pdf library.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate pdf easily using FPDF library http://www.fpdf.org/. But you can not edit them via this library. You can use FPDI library mentioned here: [PDF Editing in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364/pdf-editing-in-php).

Answer (score 0):

**Here is my view:**

It is easy to edit Hypertext rather than PDF it self. I use [TCPDF](https://tcpdf.org/examples/) to convert HTML to PDF.

Take a look at this. It might be helpful : [TCPDF_import is not bringing in an existing file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26029065/tcpdf-import-is-not-bringing-in-an-existing-file)

Thanks, Let us know if you find a better solution.